# Checking correctness of infix expression in c++

Tags: c++

I read an infix expression from the file, how can I check if it is a true or false input? I can only do 1 such case. I can think many situations but I don't know how to check in c++. Everyone please help me. Thanks very much!

```
int32_t check_error(string& str)
{
    unsigned len = str.length();
    if (str[0] != '(' || str[len-1] != ')')
    {
        return -1;
    }
    for (unsigned i = 3; i < len-3; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >='0' && str[i] <= '9' && str[i + 1] = ' ' && str[i + 2] >= '0' && str[i + 2] <= '9')
            return -2;
        if ((str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '*' || str[i] == '/' || str[i] == '%' || str[i] == '^') && (str[i - 2] < '0' || str[i - 2]>'9' || str[i + 2] < '0' || str[i + 2]>'9'))
            return -3;
        if (str[i] == ' ' && str[i + 1] == ' ')
            return -4;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `str[i + 1] = ' '` should be `str[i + 1] == ' '`

Comment: Please specify problem by providing more test data here: https://godbolt.org/z/ed4h6e8PK so we can be aware of all corner cases.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Can you help me write this function?

Comment: Updated link: https://godbolt.org/z/8r43xdajP

Comment: Sure. (1) Use `std::istringstream` combined with `std::skipws`. Do not expect an exact number of spaces. (2) To support nesting of parentheses, use a nesting counter. (Or, in the worst case, recursion, but that’s always unnecessary.) (3) Formulate a grammar that the expression must adhere to, implement a set of functions, one per state, and use them for correctness checking. For example, in a state called “beginning”, the next token can be a number or a `(`, but not an operator or `)`. Another state could be called “after a number”, expecting an operator or a `)`. And so on.